About Me is too long
I wanted to edit my Stack Overflow ‘About me’, but even making my bio shorter results in the following

Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:

About Me is too long


I can’t even save any changes to my profile due to this error message, even if I don’t change my about me at all.
What is the character limit for the about me section and when was it changed?

According to answer to: "How do you cross the 3k character limit for About Me?", the limit is 3,000 characters.

Obviously I don't get to see the Markdown source, but what I'm seeing doesn't seem like it should be bumping into the 3k limit.

Seeing the HTML representative from the API, looks like the [meta-tag:tags] expansion takes many characters due to additional attributes. Though, I don't know if it counts the markdown source or the rendered HTML.

@AndrewT. according to Makyen's link it counts the Markdown source.

@ray that the column is a MAX data type doesn't mean that [so] allows 2GB of characters; posts are also nvarchar(MAX) but don't allow ~1 Billion characters (note the documentation you link states up to 2GB worth of characters, and nvarchar characters are 2+ bytes in size, so the maximum characters is half the maximum size in bytes)

You put your favorite answers in the about me. That's actually pretty clever. Now I wish that was a dedicated profile feature.

I suppose it would be nice if you could make a Saves List public, @Gimby .

My Markdown source is only 1404 characters.

There are actually two limits at play here:

The raw markdown of your About Me can be up to 3,000 characters. When hitting this limit, you'll receive the error: "About Me is limited to # characters; you entered #"
The rendered HTML of your About Me can be up to 6,000 characters. When hitting this limit, you'll receive the error: "About Me is too long"

Both of these limits have always existed and haven't been changed. However, it is possible that changes to how we render Markdown can cause the render HTML to exceed the max length if you were already close to the limit before. The only way to resolve it is to remove parts of your About Me, likely some things that cause a lot of rendering, so that it no longer exceeds the HTML max length.

Given the answer from animuson it looks like the use of tag markdown like [tag:javascript] pushes your aboutme over the limit. This is what a HTML render of [tag:javascript] expands to (added line-breaks for readability):
<a href="/questions/tagged/javascript" 
   class="post-tag" 
   title="show questions tagged &#39;javascript&#39;" 
   aria-label="show questions tagged &#39;javascript&#39;" 
   rel="tag" 
   aria-labelledby="tag-javascript-tooltip-container"
>javascript</a>

User gre_gor found that new renders add a data-tag-menu-origin="Unknown" attribute and add s-tag in the class attribute, adding another 37 characters per tag.
Your current rendered HTML length is 5,674. Your best option is likely to reduce the number of [tag: ] markdown in your About Me.
I won't go into the uselessness of rendering an aria-labelledby attribute in the about me.
An alternative might be
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript"><kbd>javascript</kbd></a>

which renders as:

javascript

and takes somewhat less space.
It is worth noting that the tag markdown in your about me only works correctly on Stack Overflow because the tag is rendered as a relative link and here on Meta Stack Overflow there is no useful info on /questions/tagged/javascript.

The new tag rendering adds the data-tag-menu-origin="Unknown" attribute and s-tag class, which is an increase of 37 characters per tag.

@gre_gor that makes sense for a tag in the context of a Q/A page. None of that is needed nor useful in the context of an about me. I wouldn't have high hopes for an FR that asks for specific tag renderer to be used in the about me.

Odd that "About me" behaves differently for tag markdown. [tag:tagname] ([[tag:tagname]])in the comments and in a post refer to main; you need to use [meta-tag:tagname] ([[meta-tag:tagname]]) for a meta tag. Feels like a bug that about me doesn't work like that.

@ThomA It's because Meta sites don't have a separate AboutMe. It is wholesale copied from the parent site and not re-rendered. So whatever the rendering is on the main site will be the rendering on Meta too. We're not going to separately render the AboutMe for Meta just to address this edge case.
